# How to copy lower triangle to upper triangle for a 4 dimension array in Numpy Python?

Tags: python, numpy, triangular

The objective is to copy the lower triangle to upper triangle.
Based on the suggestion produced in the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16444930/6446053), the following code was drafted.

```
import numpy as np

lw_up_pair = np.tril_indices(4, -1)
arr=np.zeros((4,4,1,1))

arr[1,:1,:,0]=1
arr[2,:2,0,0]=2
arr[3,:3,0,0]=3
arr = arr + arr.T - np.diag(np.diag(arr))
```

However, it given an error

> ValueError: Input must be 1- or 2-d.

May I know how handle this issue?

The expected output is as below

```
[[[0.]],, [[1.]],, [[2.]],, [[3.]]]
[[[1.]],, [[0.]],, [[2.]],, [[3.]]]
[[[2.]],, [[2.]],, [[0.]],, [[3.]]]
[[[3.]],, [[3.]],, [[3.]],, [[0.]]]
```

Comment: What do those consecutive commas mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before performing your triangle-copy, apply a "squeeze" to squeeze out the last two axes (which have length of 1 each).

This leaves you with a 2-D array.

Then, after performing your triangle-copy, re-introduce the axes that you had squeezed out:

```
arr = np.squeeze(arr)
arr = arr + arr.T - np.diag(np.diag(arr))
arr = arr[...,None, None]
```