# Efficiently slice triangular sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse, triangular matrix (e.g. a distance matrix). In reality this would be a > 1M x 1M distance matrix with high sparsity.

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
X = csr_matrix([
      [1, 2, 3, 3, 1],
      [0, 1, 3, 3, 2],
      [0, 0, 1, 1, 3],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 3],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
])
```

I want to subset this matrix to another triangular distance matrix.
The indexes may be ordered differently and/or duplicated.

```py
idx = np.matrix([1,2,4,2])
X2 = X[idx.T, idx]
```

This may result in the resulting matrix not being triangular, with some values missing from
the upper triangle, and some values being duplicated in the lower triangle.

```py
>>> X2.toarray()
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 1]])
```

How can I get the correct upper triangle matrix as efficiently as possible?
Currently, I mirror the matrix before subsetting, and subset it to the triangle afterwards, but this doesn't feel particularly efficient, as it requires, at least, duplication of all entries.

```py
# use transpose method, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58806735/2340703
X = X + X.T - scipy.sparse.diags(X.diagonal())
X2 = X[idx.T, idx]
X2 = scipy.sparse.triu(X2, k=0, format="csr")
```

```py
>>> X2.toarray()
array([[1., 3., 2., 3.],
       [0., 1., 3., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: To clarify - you're sampling back up to the same size as your original distance matrix or you're subsetting to a smaller size?

Comment: not significantly smaller. Sometimes even larger due to repeated elements.

Comment: I'm not sure it will help, but `scipy.csr` when doing indexing like this actually creates an `extractor` matrix, and gets the result with matrix multiplication.

Comment: Just to be clear, `X2` is a valid representation of your data, right?  You are just using the `triu` to save memory?   It might also help to look at what `sparse.triu` does.  It applies a boolean mask to the `coo` array attributes, creating a new `coo` array without the lower tri values.

Comment: Yes, the idea was to save memory using `triu`. 
However, I start getting the impression that it's not worth it. Creating the `triu` appears to consume a lot of memory. Does it materialize the boolean mask?

Comment: How sparse is your upper triangular matrix? Your example is dense, but do you expect to have ~1% of values be non-zero? More? Less?

Comment: way less than 1%.
From a real-world example: `X.nnz / X.shape[0]**2` = 8.28e-05

Comment: I would consider implementing this as a compressed distance matrix in the same style that [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) does, but as a 1xN CSR matrix, and then using coordinate math to reindex it when you need to get specific values. That's a bit more of an XY solution though; I just don't think that there's a good way to do the specific thing you're asking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize all the excellent contributions, the short answer to this question is:

**Don't use triangular matrices. There's nothing to gain in terms of speed or memory compared to using square matrices.**

The reason for this is explained in [@hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65569020/2340703):

- Slicing on sparse matrices uses matrix multiplication which is super-efficient. Rearranging the matrix into a triangular shape will be slow.
- Using `triu` is an expensive operation since it materializes a dense mask.

This becomes evident when comparing [@jakevdp's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65564981/2340703) with just using a square matrix. Using the square form is faster and uses less memory.

*The test uses a sparse triangular 800k x 800k  distance matrix with high sparsity (%nnz << 1%). Data and code are available [here](https://github.com/grst/test-sparse-matrices)*.

```
# Running benchmark: Converting to square matrix
./benchmark.py squarify   6.29s  user 1.59s system 80% cpu 9.738 total
max memory:                4409 MB

# Running benchmark: @jakevdp's solution
./benchmark.py sparse_triangular   67.03s  user 3.01s system 99% cpu 1:10.15 total
max memory:                5209 MB
```

If one desperately wants to optimize this beyond using square matrices, [@CJR's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563193/efficiently-slice-triangular-sparse-matrix?noredirect=1#comment115924427_65563193) is a good starting point:

> I would consider implementing this as a compressed distance matrix in the same style that [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) does, but as a 1xN CSR matrix, and then using coordinate math to reindex it when you need to get specific values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that does not involve mirroring the data, and instead does manipulation of sparse indices to arrive at the desired result:

```python
import scipy.sparse as sp

X2 = X[idx.T, idx]

# Extract indices and data (this is essentially COO format)
i, j, data = sp.find(X2)

# Generate indices with elements moved to upper triangle
ij = np.vstack([
  np.where(i > j, j, i),
  np.where(i > j, i, j)
])

# Remove duplicate elements
ij, ind = np.unique(ij, axis=1, return_index=True)

# Re-build the matrix
X2 = sp.coo_matrix((data[ind], ij)).tocsr()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't get it to `triu` natively, but this should be faster:

```
idx = np.array([1,2,4,2])
i = np.stack(np.meshgrid(idx, idx))
X2 = X[i.min(0), i.max(0)]
 
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 1]])
```

So the whole process would be:

```
idx = np.array([1,2,4,2])
i = np.stack(np.meshgrid(idx, idx))
X2 = scipy.sparse.triu(X[i.min(0), i.max(0)], k=0, format="csr")
```

But I can't shake the feeling there's got to be a more optimized way.

Comment: interesting approach! But in its current form it wouldn't scale since the meshgrid is a dense matrix with the same dimensions as `X`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an improved working answer, but rather an exploration of what sparse indexing and `triu` does.  It might give you ideas for taking more direct calculations.  The fact that you start with a tri, and expect a tri, means this is not trivial task, not even with dense arrays (which index a whole lot faster).

`sparse.csr` indexing uses matrix multiplication.  I'll illustrate this with dense arrays:

```
In [304]: X = np.array([
     ...:       [1, 2, 3, 3, 1],
     ...:       [0, 1, 3, 3, 2],
     ...:       [0, 0, 1, 1, 3],
     ...:       [0, 0, 0, 1, 3],
     ...:       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     ...: ])
In [305]: idx = np.array([1,2,4,2])
In [306]: X[idx[:,None],idx]
Out[306]: 
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 1]])
In [307]: m = np.array([[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0,0]])
In [308]: m@X@m.T
Out[308]: 
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 1]])
```

and with the full distance array:

```
In [309]: X2 = X+X.T-np.diag(np.diag(X))
In [311]: X2[idx[:,None],idx]
Out[311]: 
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 1]])
In [312]: m@X2@m.T
Out[312]: 
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 1]])
```

I don't know if it's possible to construct a `m` that provides the desired result, upper tri or not directly from `X` (or `X2`)

```
In [316]: sparse.triu(Out[312])
Out[316]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [317]: _.A
Out[317]: 
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

`sparse.triu` does:

```
In [331]: A = sparse.coo_matrix(_312)
     ...: mask = A.row <= A.col 
In [332]: A
Out[332]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 16 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [333]: mask
Out[333]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True])
```

This `mask` array is 16 terms, `A.nnz`.

It then makes a new `coo` matrix with data/row/col arrays selected from `A` attributes:

```
In [334]: d=A.data[mask]
In [335]: r=A.row[mask]
In [336]: c=A.col[mask]
In [337]: d
Out[337]: array([1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1])
In [338]: sparse.coo_matrix((d, (r,c)))
Out[338]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [339]: _.A
Out[339]: 
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

`np.triu` uses a `mask` like:

```
In [349]: np.tri(4,4,-1)
Out[349]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```